# How do I find the maximum value in specific columns and return the corresponding value in another column of my data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that's something like this:

```
Keyword  A B C D ... X Y Z
First    1 2 3 4 ... 8 5 3
Second   2 6 2 9 ... 6 1 2
Third    3 3 2 3 ... 5 3 4
```

I've also got a list `letters` which just has the column names from A to Z.

I want to get the keyword of the maximum value in each column.

If I want to get it for just one column, something like this works:

```
max = df['A'].max()
df.loc[df['A'] == max, 'Keyword']

A Third
```

How would I go about getting it for all the columns?

So that would be:

```
A Third
B Second
C First
D Second
...
X First
Y First
Z Third
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st `set_index` then `idxmax`

```
df.set_index('Keyword').idxmax()
A     Third
B    Second
C     First
D    Second
X     First
Y     First
Z     Third
dtype: object
```

Comment: Would this work if I have other columns I don't want considered? Like for example a column `Misc` between `Keyword` and `A`

Comment: `df.set_index('Keyword').drop(['Columns1','Columns2'],1).idxmax()` @Taco

Comment: @Taco happy coding :-)

Comment: Thanks! Additional question if you don't mind. Let's say the `Misc` column has a bunch of values from 0 to 1. Now if I only want to consider rows where `Misc` is between 0.6 and 0.8, how would I go about that?

Comment: @Taco `df.set_index('Keyword').drop(['Columns1','Columns2'],1)[df.Misc.between(0.6,0.8)].idxmax()`

Comment: Thank you, you're a lifesaver! :)